# How to display the entire month dates as a header for the particular month selected

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to Angularjs, i want to display the entire month dates as a header, when im selected from the date picker for that particular month dates should be display like that only for other month based on the selection, to check the attendance of the employee

Comment: To display the attendance sheet for the employees like jan1(present), 2jan(absent),3jan(wOff),4jan(holiday)... but dates should be display according to the month dates are present, like jan is having 31-days, feb is having 29 days based on that header should display

Comment: Which means you want to show all the dates related to month like if I select January then all of the dates should be displayed in header from 1st to 31st Is that so which you are trying to do??

Comment: yes exactly but angularjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this:

**create month HTML which will be:**

```
<select ng-model="calculate.months" ng-change="monthCalculate(calculate.months)">
            <option ng-repeat="x in monthsValue" value="{{x.value}}">{{x.name}}</option>
        </select>
```

in app.js

```
 $scope.monthsValue = [
            {name: "January", value: "1"},
            {name: "February", value: "2"},
            {name: "march", value: "3"}
        ];
```

for dynamic month bind.

**lets print month days in angularjs:**

Selected Month : {{ calculate.months}}

```
    <div ng-model="totalDays">
        <div ng-repeat="i in range(totalDays) track by $index">
            <span> {{$index + 1}} </span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and in app.js :

```
$scope.monthCalculate = function (months) {
            getMonthDays = daysInMonth(months, 2016);
            $scope.totalDays = getMonthDays;
        };

        function daysInMonth(month, year) {
            return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
        }

        $scope.range = function (n) {
            return new Array(n);
        };
```

Lets give it a try Hope this helps you.

check working demo here :

https://jsfiddle.net/randheer/atf7L4hL/

Thanks
Randheer

Comment: Thanks for answering to my question but i do have a calendar picker which select month and year, no drop down through that i need to select..

Comment: <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-3" 
          datepicker-popup="MMM-yyyy" min-mode="month" datepicker-mode="'month'"
          ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" close-on-date-selection="true"
          datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" 
          show-button-bar="false" show-weeks="false"/>
          <span class="input-group-btn"> 
         <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)">
           <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
         </button>
          </span>
        </p>

Comment: then you can pass the value of year and month thta's it. I think you can do that.

Comment: javascript       $scope.today = function() {
    $scope.dt = new Date();
  };
  $scope.today();

  $scope.showWeeks = false;


  $scope.open = function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();

    $scope.opened = true;
  };

  $scope.dateOptions = {
    'year-format': "'yy'",
    'starting-day': 1,
    'datepicker-mode':"'month'",
    'min-mode':"month"
  };

Comment: sorry, but it hard to understand what you are posting here, and one more thing please mark yes if above answer helps you.